# Why are Wawrinka and Murray allowed to play in Queen's without wildcard?

Tags: tennis, ranking, atp

This week the [London Queen's Club tourney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Queen%27s_Club_Championships_%E2%80%93_Singles) is taking place, the round of 32 started on Monday June 18th 2018.

Stan Wawrinka is currently ranked ATP #261, and Andy Murry is ranked ATP# 156

According to the [Draw (PDF)](http://www.protennislive.com/posting/2018/311/mds.pdf) the "Last Direct Acceptance" is Ryan Harison with ATP #59 rank.

Why are Wawrinka and Murray allowed to play without a wildcard if their ATP ranking isn't high enough? They also don't marked as PR (Protected Ranking).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To enter a tournament at the ATP level the ranking 6 weeks before the Monday of the week of the tournament is relevant. Therefore, for Queen's the ranking of 07.05.2018 is relevant. At that time Murray was ranked #39 and Wawrinka was ranked #25, both good enough to get directly accepted into the main draw. See the entry list [here](https://www.menstennisforums.com/6368-fever-tree-championships/943762-london-queens-club-entry-list.html).

See in the [rulebook](https://www.atpworldtour.com/en/corporate/rulebook) at *7.13 Selection of Entries / A. Singles Main Draw / 1) Direct Acceptances.*

> Direct acceptances are players accepted directly in the draw by virtue
>   of their position in the ATP Rankings or by their protected ranking
>   position (singles). The list to be used for ATP World Tour tournaments
>   shall be dated approximately forty-two (42) days prior to the Monday
>   of the (first) tournament week and twenty-one (21) days prior to the
>   Monday of the tournament week for ATP Challenger Tour tournaments.